# Django Admin page with Apache2

Tags: css, django, apache, django-admin, apache-config

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook and I am using Django 1.6.4 (with virtualenv) together with Apache 2.4.7.

I have set up a django project that is located under my home directory in `/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django` (kleyboldt is the name of the guy I am writing this project for). This folder contains my virtual `env` folder (django and south installed), my `kleyboldt.wsgi` and the actual project called `kleyboldt_homepage`. To make my site ready for production I wrote a config file to create a VirtualHost serving this site:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/mks.conf**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mks.com python-path=/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage:/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mks.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /robots.txt /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/favicon.ico

    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static-only/css/$1

    Alias /media/ /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/static/

    Alias /static/admin/ /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt.wsgi

    ServerName mks.com

    Alias /static /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I edited `/etc/hosts` in order to redirect `mks.com` to my local maschine. The settings file looks like that:

**/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/kleyboldt_homepage/settings.py**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
...
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static-only')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'templates'),
)

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'homepage',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
...
```

In kleyboldt_homepage/static/ are four folder: `media` (data uploaded by the user which you should not trust), `static` (folders `css`, `fonts`, `img` and `js` for Bootstrap), static-only (contains `admin`, `css`, `fonts`, `img` and `js`after `./manage.py collectstatic`) and `templates`.

Unfortunately my admin site is still without css and opening the css files in the source code leads to an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `python manage.py collectstatic` after setting up `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` in your settings.py